# change color of fixed image after scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll

I want to change the color of a simple icon from white to black - and back - after a certain amount of scrolling (due to change in background color). See http://www.euimpact.com/erikverwey and scroll down - you'll see what I mean).

Now I'm hoping to do this in CSS/JQuery somehow and have a smooth transition, i.e. it'd be possible for the image to be half black half white when crossing the line.

But I'm guessing that's not possible, is it?

Would I just have to switch to a different image at a certain scrolling point?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This can be achieved using CSS.  See [my answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21979960/change-logo-in-every-div-of-my-html-page/21980708#21980708).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible to have different colors on the edge

But to change the color you can use window scroll

A <kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chauhangs/4CwS4/)</kbd>

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
     if($(window).scrollTop()<800){
            $('#fixed').css('background-color','Yellow');
      }else{
          $('#fixed').css('background-color','White');
    }
})
```

I created another <kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chauhangs/42Rqf/)</kbd> for you where the div changes the color on edge, but I have done the complete mathematic, so you will see some issues. But you can play around the fiddle to find out the exact values to make that working for you.

Comment: Look at the other fiddle as well